# how to do a sumifs / vlookup -ish formular on pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Very beginner in python here. I would like to do some simple computation for basic option analysis as shown in the three sets of DataFrame (spot_table, div_table, opt_table).

What I am looking for here is to do a similar thing as excel's "sumifs" function in python to come up with the "desired result" table.

1. Applied dividend (a_div)
     e.g. For each option contract in opt_table would look for the corresponding und and Ex-date from the div_table. Any dividend that falls before options expiry would be included in the a_div column.

   Applied spot (a_spot)
     e.g. For each option contract in opt_table would look for the corresponding spot price from the spot_table.

```
spot_table
     Spot  Trade_date  und
0  197.20  2017-05-29  AAA
1   67.75  2017-05-29  BBB
2  274.80  2017-05-29  CCC

div_table
   Div     Ex-date  und
0    1  2017-09-01  AAA
1    2  2017-10-01  AAA
2    4  2017-11-01  AAA
3   10  2017-10-01  BBB
4   20  2017-11-01  BBB
5  100  2017-09-01  CCC

opt_table
       Expiry  Opt  und
0  2017-10-15  ZZZ  AAA
1  2017-11-01  YYY  AAA
2  2017-10-30  XXX  BBB
3  2017-12-20  WWW  CCC
```

**desired result**

```
   a_Div    Expiry  Opt  und  a_Spot
0    3  2017-10-15  ZZZ  AAA  197.20
1    7  2017-11-01  YYY  AAA  197.20
2   10  2017-10-30  XXX  BBB   67.75
3  100  2017-12-20  WWW  CCC  274.80
```

Comment: Look into `pd.merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a few steps. First, join the spot table to option table on the underlying:

```
opt_spot=pd.merge(opt_table, spot_table, how='left', on='und')
```

Next, assign a new column to the dividend table to identify the **latest** dividend paid (I assume this is what you want?):

```
div_table['latest'] = div_table.sort_values(['und', 'Ex-date'], ascending=False).groupby('und').cumcount()+1
```

Join the new table with latest dividend for each underlying (not sure if this is the best way of doing this):

```
desired_output = pd.merge(opt_spot, div_table[div_table['latest'] == 1], how='left', on='und')
```

Rename and drop columns you don't want:

```
final_output = desired_output.rename_axis({'Div':'a_Div', 'Spot': 'a_Spot'}, axis=1)[['a_Div', 'Expiry', 'Opt', 'und', 'a_Spot']]
```

Comment: thx Andrew. The 'Spot' worked after the merging method (opt_spot=pd.merge(opt_table, spot_table, how='left', on='und') as suggested. However for the dividend part, each option contracts needs to look at the underlying and ex-date. So I was trying to come up with a function then apply it to the df. (df ['a_div'] = df.apply(function_that_works, axis=1) def acc_div (x):
    acc_div = 0
    for r in opt_table.iterrows():
        for i in div_table_.iterrows():
            if r['und'] == i['und'] and r['Expiry'] >= i['Ex-date']:
                acc_div += i['Div']
        return acc_div

Comment: @clem - can you explain? Does your function work? You'll probably want to ask another question since this is outside the scope of merging dataframes.